# How to troubleshoot performance difference between 2 web servers?

Tags: php, ubuntu, web, apache2, intranet

I have a production virtual web server that is being migrated to a new virtual web server on the same local network.  The problem is that there is a performance problem on the new server.

For example, there is one page that loads in about 1 second on the original server, but takes over 25 seconds to load on the new one.  I have already ruled out the database connection as the problem.

Both servers are Ubuntu Apache servers running PHP.  There are slight differences in the versions of the servers, I will list as best I can here.

**My main question is**: is there a general way to profile the web requests on each server?

Similar to the way I can profile a python script or function and get a break-down of which parts of the program take the most time, I would like to profile the web requests on one server compared to the other.

Of course a web requests to the server are fundamentally different than programs run on a local computer, but I need to find where the bottleneck is.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Old Server Config**
Ubuntu 14.04 - PHP version 5.5.9

**New Server Config** 
Ubuntu 16.04 - PHP version 5.6.31 (also tested with version 7, same result)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to log PHP script execution time.
If it comes from somewhere in the PHP execution, you will notice it easily.
Do a log at the start and one at the end. Then you can stress test both and see different execution time.
I seriously doubt the problem comes from PHP but if you do that you could also see differences with PHP7 which should be 30% faster.

Comment: I doubt it is PHP as well that's why I was thinking of being able to profile the entire request transaction somehow.  I think there is something about this server that is slowly down transmission after the PHP has completed.

Comment: It might be, but the easiest thing to test is inside PHP script. It could come from db implementation or anything else including a php lib.